# Lighthouse: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

When i check site speed using [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

I am not able to see result and get error message like below :

```
Lighthouse: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. net::ERR_TIMED_OUT.
```

I already added right URL of  the site.
URL : https://localandinterstateremovals.com.au/

Please any one help me.

Comment: have you solved it? we're having the same problem.

Comment: I've also this issue. I deactivated all plugins and checked in page speed and seems its working. Then I tried activating each plugin and run page speed . While doing this I understand that WP Super Cache was causing the issue. I removed the plugin and cleared all cache folder manually and reinstalled and the issue fixed.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is quite often reported by many users.

It occurs because of the following issues:

1. Unresponsive server
2. Unstable internet connection.

Please try to rerun the test then it will work.

For more clear and better result follow instructions in this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/#devtools).

Comment: You're quite right, most tools I depend on for website performance check failed with no errors except Chrome Builtin Lighthouse, produced a **502 - Bad Gateway**

Answer (score 0):

I think you site has problem with SSL (I use Cyberpanel Let's Encrypt SSL)
Wait some days later, fix SSL, problem will be solved