# error on Google Page Speed Insights and doesn't run on one website I made,

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, google-pagespeed

I tried to run [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexecfarm.com%2F) and got this error message. I've searched and can't seem to find how to fix that. I also ran Page Speed Insights with other websites that I made and every time it worked.

> Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)

```
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexecfarm.com%2F
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe you had a temporary server glitch?

Comment: I tried it again in several different browsers and still get the same error message

Comment: It must have been temporary, because it failed for me twice but works now. Also, side note you should fix your robots.txt file

Comment: Well that may be an issue with the specific google server that handles your (local) request. The google server that's running it for me works perfectly.

Comment: there is no any error. works fine

Comment: I'm not working on the page. I made the page and uploaded it like I always do

Comment: I assume you're not cloud hosting this website?

Comment: I use ipower.com to host about 100 websites. This is the 1st time I've had the erro

Comment: what webserver are you running? nginx, apache? did you force http requests to redirect to https?

Comment: Three questions - 1. did you fiddle with your Windows hosts file at any point during development, 2. are you using Brave browser, 3. Do you have a custom firewall or VPN? Oh and does this link work (do you get a full JSON response after a few seconds) https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexecfarm.com%2F

Comment: @mlegg have you received the error above from the first run (and keep receiving it), or did you receive it after doing the test repeatedly?

Answer (score 4):

Several of us in comments 
have tried the link you gave and have not experienced any errors.

However, I have been refreshing the page and the Google Speed insights result has been showing different values for the page overall score From 34%, to 40% to 70% (then back to 40%).

This would possibly imply that the page is being worked on or that there is some other (database) stuff that is changing each time the page is loaded.

If you are not cloudhosting (ie Cached copies) then when your server is taking up a new file uploaded from your IDE, while that file is uploaded to the server it can not be "read" while it's being "written". So maybe Google is trying to access the file when it is being replaced which will cause momentary drops.

---

You should also be forcing the HTTPS, currently the website is still fully accessible on the insecure `http://execfarm.com` URL.

Comment: In the control panel I click on security for the domain and it says: "Let's Encrypt Free SSL

Secure your website with a free SSL from Let's Encrypt.

execfarm.com free SSL is currently ENABLED."

Comment: You need to force HTTPS. It's there as an option but it's not *forced*.

Comment: random question @Martin why did you make this a wiki? Does that stop you getting the bounty? I am guessing it is because you gave a 'best guess' answer as OP hasn't provided enough info / problem cannot be replicated - if that is why then thank you for introducing me to a way to answer where I normally wouldn't. If that isn't why then I am intrigued and would love to be enlightened! :-)

Comment: Hi @GrahamRitchie , that's a good question -- tbh I am not certain - I think that because I believe the question itself should be deleted as it's not a reproducable issue (see comments) and it's about the workings of a 3rd party system. However, because the question has a bounty it can't be closed or deleted. I think my answer is really just a big comment rather than an actual answer, and so I am happy for others to add details here as appropriate because the question itself can not be answered. cheers

Answer (score 0):

try to force redirection to https instead of http by activate SSL

Answer (score 0):

I tried the test 10 times and all of them failed with

> Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)

This could mean multiple things. Either your page failed to render in Google's PageSpeed Insights, an internet backbone broke, or something else happened.

It may be that an internet backbone outage that caused your server's connection with Google to be broken. When an internet backbone outage happens, user A may be able to connect to your server, but user B may not. To rule this out, check your logs when you go to your Google PageSpeed Insights and look for any IP address associated with Google's IPs.

To rule out that page rendering is the cause, move your index.html file to somewhere else, and replace it with a dummy index.html, to ensure that page rendering isn't the cause.

To rule out an internet backbone outage, switch to a temporary server and move everything there. If Google PageSpeed Insights works, then you know that it was an internet backbone outage.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem because of my SSL integration. After fixed it, my problem solved. Try to run lighthouse test without SSL.

Also please check this answer:

> This issue is quite often reported by many users.
>
> It occurs because of the following issues:
>
> Unresponsive server Unstable internet connection. Please try to rerun
>   the test then it will work.
>
> For more clear and better result follow instructions in this link.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/53318088/4766521